# Main super user app not working on Redmi note 6 pro

Tags: xiaomi

I rooted my n6p (after unlock of bootloader) using TWRP and flashed Magisk which installed Magisk manager. Many root checkers showed my phone was positively rooted.  After that I was using titanium backup as superuser  app, it was working fine and other apps also got super user access. But titanium b. has known issues with Magisk (https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/672). 
After titanium backup was denied superuser access a couple of times I tried to uninstall and install tb, but now it just keeps stopping whenever I open it. 
I tried using all sorts of superuser apps, root explorers, bash scripts, ads remover etc but ALL of them are "denied superuser rights". 
Also other super user apps including tb I install are not detected by Magisk. 
Thanks, I'm new here so sorry if I left out any details.

Comment: Maybe uninstall and re-install Magisk?

Comment: Flashing Magisk Canary is an option too

Comment: Yeah but I'm scared that uninstalling it will result in it stop working too and I'll have to flash it again

Comment: Right now also it's not working..... Your call

Comment: don't mix up magisk with other superuser apps. if you uninstall magisk manager from settings - apps only, your device keep it's current modifications (so you can just install magisk manager apk any time) try another backup app http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=balti.migrate